# Sphinx make file may be using wrong docutils file

Tags: python, makefile, python-sphinx

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrcj7sVuvUA) tutorial on how to get started with [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) documentation for python.

On my mac, I run the make command

```
$ make html
```

(as instructed around minute 09:25 in the video), however I get the error

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/writers/html4css1/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from docutils.writers import _html_base
ImportError: cannot import name _html_base
```

From the error, it seems the make file is using an older python 2.7 version of `docutils` that came installed with the Mac. I believe the make file should be using a more recent version of `docutils` located here

```
/Users/me/anaconda/pkgs/sphinx-1.6.3-py36hcd1b3e7_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/utils/docutils.py
```

This file does not import the package `_html_base`, which seems to be the problem with the python 2.7 version of the `docutils` file.

How can I "point the make file to use the python 3.6 docutils"? if that question makes sense. Or is there a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you installed sphinx via the command `pip install -U sphinx` where `pip` points to Mac's Python2.7

In order to overcome this, you need to `pip3 install -U sphinx` (if you have a Python3.x available).